# View CoffeeScript as Compiled JavaScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, sublimetext

[image]

I am trying to learn coffeescript. I installed the Sublime package 'BetterCoffeeScript', and I am seeing the syntax highlighting, but I can't figure out how to view my coffeescript as compiled javascript. When I go to the command pallet and click Coffee: Display JS, it just generates a new blank file. How do I get this to show the compiled JS? Also, what is the first key that is shown for the keyboard shortcut? I attached a screenshot.

Comment: The `Alt/Option` key.

Comment: Did you actually install copfescript and configure the package according to the [manuals](https://github.com/aponxi/sublime-better-coffeescript#settings)? If so, some pathes and settings may help.

Comment: @makadev I installed coffeescript and am using it in a small practice program. It is compiling when I run it in the browser, just when I try to view to compiled JS in Sublime, I am not able to. I added a few of the settings, that I thought might help like "showOutputOnSave" and "compileOnSave", but I am still not able to get it to work. Have you used this before? What do your sublime settings look like for BetterSC?

Comment: @adamscott I'm not using sublime and can only give you advice from experience with other tools. Your Problem sounds like [this issue](https://github.com/aponxi/sublime-better-coffeescript/issues/142), which seems to be due to wrong environment settings. It may be better if you add additional information to your Question: Are you using Win/OSX/Linux? Where is the coffeescript transpiler installed (PATH)? Maybe add your settings. Be sure to obfuscate everything with personal information.

Comment: @makadev you were right. I needed to change my path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer taken from https://github.com/aponxi/sublime-better-coffeescript/issues/142

In terminal, run which coffee to see where coffee is installed.

If it's `/usr/bin/coffee`, you should be fine.

If it's `/usr/local/bin/coffee` (or anything else), go to `Sublime, Preferences > Package Settings > Better CoffeeScript > Settings - User`

Add `"binDir": "/usr/local/bin"` (or whatever which said it was) there.